# Can I replace an await method; return with a call to an async Task?

Tags: c#

I have this code in a method of my application. If the condition is not met then the SetMessageAsync is called and the method returns:

```
if (x != true)
{
   await SetMessageViewAsync("X");
   return;
}
```

I tried to refactor the code and it was suggested I could use this code to replace it:

```
if (x != true)
{
   await NewMethod();
   // return; <<< should there be a return statement here?
}

private async Task NewMethod()
{
   await SetMessageViewAsync("X");
   return;
}
```

My question is, should there be a return statement after the await NewMethod?

Comment: If anything non-trivial follows your `if` block, then yes.

Comment: its hard to tell. you have to follow your logic.

Comment: I would replace `if (x != true)` with `if(!x)`. And also, how is the rest of the method looking?

Comment: If you take `async` and `await` out and just looked at the synchronous equivalent, would you need the `return`? The answer is the same in the asynchronous world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return statement in the "inner" method will only have the effect of ending the "NewMethod" processing. Execution of the outer method will continue normally. So, if there is more code after the call, that you don't want executed, you should have the return statement there as well.